# How to install graphic capabilities to CoreOs?

Tags: drivers, lxc, gpu, coreos

I would like to install CoreOs as a base on my desktop machine. Then, I could launch some containers, with eventualy a graphical environnement.

So I have to add all the graphic stack: GPU drivers, X11 server,... to my base distribution.

My goal is to have a stable system, and also to go deeper in my comprehension of how containers works and also graphical environnements.

Comment: And what is the question? Maybe you should include a sentence with a question mark into your post.

Comment: Something like: How to install graphic capabilities to CoreOs? I am going to change the title.

Answer (score 4):

This [Dockerfile](https://github.com/rogaha/docker-desktop/blob/master/Dockerfile) from this [blog post](https://blog.docker.com/2013/07/docker-desktop-your-desktop-over-ssh-running-inside-of-a-docker-container/) demonstrate an ideal way to get started with a Linux GUI running in a (Docker) container. A similar setup can be achieved using a CoreOS machine(s) as a host, and X11 and SSHD running inside the container. In the example I linked, the author also included software like the JRE (Java), Firefox, LibreOffice, and a Desktop/Window Manager (Fluxbox). You don't necessarily need to include this in your container, for instance, you could include the awesome WM, Chromium, and xterm. The author is also using Ubuntu as his docker base image, you might decide to use, for instance, Debian or Arch Linux.